# Dynamic object and AJAX call mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

How to do an `AJAX` call to a `MVC` `Controller` that expects a `dynamic` `object`?

This was my try:

```
public JsonResult Test(dynamic someObject)
{
    return;
}


$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/home/test',
     data: JSON.stringify( { test: 1, test2: 2 } ),
     contentType: 'application/json',

     success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
     },
     error: function (error, data) {
         alert("something went wrong: " + error );
    }
});
```

But I get just {object} as a value in `someObject`.

Comment: I don't believe the MVC model binder can bind with a dynamic object.

Comment: Is there another way then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible because MVC cannot deserialize an object that it doesn't know a type for.

I recommend passing the data in as a JSON string and then deserializing that.

```
public JsonResult Test(string someObject)
{
    dynamic y = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(someObject);
    return;
}
```

JavaScriptSerializer can be found in System.Web.Extensions

Comment: +1 - however (and this is the OP's issue, rather than your answer), by using dynamic, you may be doing yourself a dis-service in terms of maintainability. if you expect a variety of different class objects to be desrialised in that actionmethod, i'd recommend using a common interface against the classes that you *expect* to be deserializing

Comment: @drizzie, shouldn't I fake a view model in stead of using `string`? The 'someobject' is always null.

Comment: If it is always null, there is something incorrect about your AJAX call.  If you use a ViewModel, then you are using a strongly typed class, which eliminates the need for using JavaScriptSerialier and a dynamic object all together.  This is what @jimtollan is saying in his comment.  It is definitely better to use a ViewModel.

Comment: I ported the project to WebApi. Thanks for your help.